# How to prevent AUTO INCREMENT table from indexed as array on PHP at SQL SERVER?

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, database

There is something wrong in my PHP script when inserting values into the SQL SERVER table.

Here's the script :

```
<?php

include_once 'core/init.php';

function report_cctv(){

#info utama seluruh fungsi
global $conn;
$notif = '';

#data input laporan pelanggaran
$array_pelanggaran = [$_POST['w'],
                      $_POST['n'],
                      $_POST['j'],
                      $_POST['l'],
                      $_POST['b']];
$data_pelanggaran = "'" . implode("','", $array_pelanggaran) . "'";

#data input laporan kerusakan
$array_kerusakan = [$_POST['w2'],
                    $_POST['n2'],
                    $_POST['j2'],
                    $_POST['l2'],
                    $_POST['b2']];
$data_kerusakan = "'" . implode("','", $array_kerusakan) . "'";

#data input laporan lain
$array_lain = [$_POST['w3'],
               $_POST['n3'],
               $_POST['j3'],
               $_POST['l3'],
               $_POST['b3']];
$data_lain = "'" . implode("','", $array_lain) . "'";

//query laporan pelanggaran
$query   =  "INSERT INTO pelanggaran VALUES ($data_pelanggaran)";
//query laporan kerusakan
$query2   =  "INSERT INTO laporan_kerusakan VALUES ($data_kerusakan)";
//query laporan lain
$query3   =  "INSERT INTO laporan_lain VALUES ($data_lain)";


if(strlen(isset($data_pelanggaran)) > 0) {
  sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

  if (strlen(isset($data_kerusakan)) > 0) {
    sqlsrv_query($conn,$query2);

      if (strlen(isset($data_lain)) > 0) {
        sqlsrv_query($conn,$query3);
      }else {
        echo "data lain gagal diinput";
      }

  }else {
    echo "data kerusakan gagal diinput";
  }

}else {
  echo "data pelanggaran gagal diinput";
}

}

?>
```

When i run that script, it is successful to insert the data into the server, but the ID table is automatically added the value even i did inserted those arrays into different tables and ignoring the other table with empty field.

This is the first data, I inserted it in the "laporan_kerusakan" table :

Please look at this pic and see the id column, it was set normally and starts from 1.

[image: please look at this pic and see the id column, it was set normally and starts from 1]

But when I inserted a new data into the another table, the ID doesn't start at 1 anymore, which means it saving the first ID value as array and inserting it at the other table as 2.

ID started from 2 at the other table.

[image: ID started from 2 at the other table]

Can anyone explain why this is happen, please ? also, is there any solution to fix this problem ?

thank you very much before, and I'm sorry for my bad speaking..

**EDIT :**

I just want to insert data on each form by only 1 button on the page without affecting the other table which has auto increment value.

**example :**

I'm inserting the first value like the first picture above, and i want to insert other data to the other table.

But when I click the submit button for the second time, the result is like the second picture above. The ID column was started with "2" rather than "1". How to fix it ?

Here's my SQL table creation script as requested before, and I trnaslated the field name from indonesian into english language :

```
use dailyreport

/* table pelanggaran (violation table) */
create table pelanggaran(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
  violation_time varchar(5),
  violation_suspect varchar(100),
  id_type_of_violation int,
  id_store_location int,
  screenshot_proof text
);

/* table laporan_kerusakan (damage_report)  */
create table laporan_kerusakan(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
  damaged_time varchar(5),
  damage_detail varchar(100),
  id_type_of_damaged_things int,
  id_damaged_things_location int,
  screenshot_proof text
);

/* table laporan_lain (other_report)  */
create table laporan_lain(
  id int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
  other_time varchar(5),
  other_detail varchar(100),
  id_other_report int,
  id_other_report_location int,
  screenshot_proof text
);
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear, can you explain better? You can't have rows with the same ID in the table, auto-incrementing columns will increment automatically. Is there some relationship between the different tables that you're not explaining?

Comment: When you defined your tables, how did you define the ID?  Please show us the syntax used for tables creation, that might explain what is going on.  *But* if you need the id to be unique between two tables, because they somehow represent the same object, you should use foreign keys, not force the ID to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some editing in my script, i found the problem itself..

all i need to do is just deleting the `!empty` function from the script and give some condition to prevent all queries from running at the same time when i click the button. The id is not inserted normally because when the button submitted, the whole queries is running. The `,` and `'` symbols from the arrays is detected as a strings.

This is the modification of the codes :

```
<?php

include_once 'core/init.php';

function report_cctv(){
error_reporting(0);



#info utama seluruh fungsi
global $conn;
$notif = '';

#data input laporan pelanggaran
$array_pelanggaran = [$_POST['w'],
                      $_POST['n'],
                      $_POST['j'],
                      $_POST['l'],
                      $_FILES['upload']['name'][0]];
$data_pelanggaran = "'" . implode("','", $array_pelanggaran) . "'";

#data input laporan kerusakan
$array_kerusakan = [$_POST['w2'],
                    $_POST['n2'],
                    $_POST['j2'],
                    $_POST['l2'],
                    $_FILES['upload']['name'][1]];
$data_kerusakan = "'" . implode("','", $array_kerusakan) . "'";

#data input laporan lain
$array_lain = [$_POST['w3'],
               $_POST['n3'],
               $_POST['j3'],
               $_POST['l3'],
               $_FILES['upload']['name'][2]];
$data_lain = "'" . implode("','", $array_lain) . "'";


    /* Script to test the result of the inserted values */
    // echo "<br />";
    // var_dump($data_pelanggaran); echo "<br />";
    // var_dump($data_kerusakan); echo "<br />";
    // var_dump($data_lain); echo "<br />"; exit();


//query laporan pelanggaran
$query    =  "INSERT INTO pelanggaran VALUES ($data_pelanggaran)";
//query laporan kerusakan
$query2   =  "INSERT INTO laporan_kerusakan VALUES ($data_kerusakan)";
//query laporan lain
$query3   =  "INSERT INTO laporan_lain VALUES ($data_lain)";



/* Data insert functions */
if(strlen($data_pelanggaran) > 14) {
  sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);

  /* Script for testing which queries are running */
  // print_r('<br /><div class="text-center"><h1>TESTING INPUT DATA : DATA PELANGGARAN</h1><br /><h2 style="font-weight:bold;">'. $data_pelanggaran .'</h2></div>');
  // echo '<br /><div class="text-center"><p style="font-weight:bold;">Jumlah string <b>data pelanggaran</b> yang terbaca adalah : '. strlen($data_pelanggaran) .'</h2></div>';
}

if (strlen($data_kerusakan) > 14) {
  sqlsrv_query($conn,$query2);
  // print_r('<br /><div class="text-center"><h1>TESTING INPUT DATA : DATA KERUSAKAN</h1><h2 style="font-weight:bold;">' . $data_kerusakan .'</h2></div>');
  // echo '<br /><div class="text-center"><br /><p style="font-weight:bold;">Jumlah string <b>data kerusakan</b> yang terbaca adalah : '. strlen($data_kerusakan) .'</h2></div>';
}

if (strlen($data_lain) > 14) {
  sqlsrv_query($conn,$query3);
  // print_r('<br /><div class="text-center"><h1>TESTING INPUT DATA : DATA LAIN</h1><br /><h2 style="font-weight:bold;">' . $data_lain .'</h2></div>');
  // echo '<br /><div class="text-center"><p style="font-weight:bold;">Jumlah string <b>data lain</b> yang terbaca adalah : '. strlen($data_lain) .'</h2></div>';
}


}




?>
```

Thank you so much for the help guys !

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

When you have AUTO INCREMENT columns,

You can use NULL in place of auto increment column, as in --

```
//query laporan pelanggaran
$query   =  "INSERT INTO pelanggaran VALUES ( NULL ,$data_pelanggaran)";
//query laporan kerusakan
$query2   =  "INSERT INTO laporan_kerusakan VALUES ( NULL ,$data_kerusakan)";
//query laporan lain
$query3   =  "INSERT INTO laporan_lain VALUES ( NULL ,$data_lain)";
```

Otherwise if the order of insertion is not same as the order of columns, then data will be inserted wrongly or an error is thrown.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice sir, i already tried that, but it does not fix the problem. When i try to insert data and added NULL to it, it shows nothing, the data doesn't inserted, and there is no error notice.

Comment: okay try `"INSERT INTO table(col1,col2,..) values(value1,value2,..)". That is by specifying the column names and values in order in each insert.

Comment: same result, sir... the id is still start from the last inserted value...